# XSLT parser/content error xml to text for doctype cesAlign

Tags: xml, xslt, text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="linkGrp">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> <!-- newline after sentences -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I attempt to run the above xslt stylesheet on the following cesAlign xml doc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cesAlign PUBLIC "-//CES//DTD XML cesAlign//EN" "">
<cesAlign version="1.0">
<linkGrp targType="s" fromDoc="en/1976/7277/69682_1of1.xml.gz" toDoc="zh/1976/7277/4041906_1of1.xml.gz">
<link id="SL0" xtargets=";1" />
<link id="SL1" xtargets="1;2" />
<link id="SL2" xtargets="2;3" />
...
```

I encounter this error:

```
parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!DOCTYPE cesAlign PUBLIC "-//CES//DTD XML cesAlign//EN" "">
```

Is there some place where I should be specifying this particular input doc type (cesAlign)?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure what the expected output should look like - `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>` will result in nothing as it is a function that should be applied on a string and not on a node - I just wrote a small XSLT getting the attribute values, together with some text as identifiers. Specifying the input doc type wasn't needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="linkGrp "/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="linkGrp">
  <xsl:text>linkGrp&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>targType: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@targType"/>
  <xsl:text>, fromDoc: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@fromDoc"/>
  <xsl:text>, toDoc: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@toDoc"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./link"/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;link&#xa;id: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/>
  <xsl:text>, xtargets: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="./@xtargets"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result (`toDoc` just moved manually for better readability):

```
linkGrp
targType: s, fromDoc: en/1976/7277/69682_1of1.xml.gz, 
             toDoc: zh/1976 /7277/4041906_1of1.xml.gz

link
id: SL0, xtargets: ;1

link
id: SL1, xtargets: 1;2

link
id: SL2, xtargets: 2;3
```

In case the required output should look totally different just update this in your question as it's not clear if you would like to get the attribute values of the link groups and links or kind of a copy of the whole nodes.

For reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space